# How to decrypt raw TLS bytes?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, tls, openssl, decryption

Is there any tool / way to decrypt raw bytes of a **TLS 1.2** session, when the **master key** is known, even if forward secrecy is used?

The closest I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198379/decrypt-tls-1-2-aes-gcm-packet).

I know its possible using [Wireshark](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/decrypting-tls-in-wireshark-when-using-dhe-rsa-ciphersuites), but I am intrested in decrypting raw TLS bytes (without the underlying protocols) as described [here](https://tls.ulfheim.net/).

An example input (without the master key) is [this](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/testdata/Client-TLSv12-ECDHE-ECDSA-AES).

Comment: Although this should definitely be possible, please understand that TLS is considered a single layer. So having it partially altered by only decrypting seems a bit strange. Replacing just the ciphertext with the received plaintext seems most logical (although you'd probably loose some of the MAC authentication tag for the CBC based cipher suites).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have been looking into the internals of TLS and it does look possible indeed, after parsing client / server hellos and extracting session keys from the master key. Yet to find a tool though. I will code it and maybe post it here too

Comment: One little issue, with CBC the size of the plaintext may be hidden up to the size of the block size of the underlying block cipher (16 bytes for AES).

Comment: I'm *extremly* interested in the answer to this, and/but/therefore think it might be a better fit for [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) -- Could it be migrated?